# Получение сообщений андроидом от firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть десяток андроидов, все подписаны на topic firebase.
Сообщения не содержат заголовка (notification) только date и не много.

Когда приложение убираешь из памяти - сообщения не доходят, **но только** до некоторых телефонов. Системы никакой, разные производители и версии 6,7,8.

Например Huawei на андроид 8 ловит, а на 6 - нет.

Sony на 6 ловит, Samsung на 8 - нет.

ловлю и через `onMessageReceived()` и через `onReceive()`,
и по переменке и одновременно.

Но как только запускаешь приложение сразу все прилетает.

Чего не учел?

Вот основной код:

```
public class FirebaseDataReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Public.toLog(" Получил ... onReceive");
  }
}


public class GetFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
            Public.toLog(" Получил ... onMessageReceived");
      }
    }
```

В манифесте:

```
    <service android:name=".Message.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".Message.GetFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".Message.FirebaseDataReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Выяснилось, что причиной всего является настройки батареи в настройках приложения. Т.е. некая система появилась.

Comment: Оповещения с сервера идут по приоритету high

Answer (score 1):

В целом вопрос сводиться к запуску приложения в фоновом режиме.
Если системой разрешен такой запуск приложения, то работает, если нет - нет.
У некоторых моделей после установки по умолчанию такой режим отключен,
включаешь его руками работает,
как его включить программно не понятно.
[тут понимается этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/885684/%D0%92%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)