# Включить программно кнопку в настройках телефона

Tags: java, android

андроид 6.0 HUAWEI идем в настройки:
Настройки - приложения и уведомления - приложения - myApp - батарея:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

андроид 8.0 HUAWEI идем в настройки:
Настройки - приложения и уведомления - приложения - myApp - батарея - запуск:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как программно переключить эти переключатели?

Хотя бы на этапе первого запуска, как пермишенсы ....